# Type constraints in CaseReducer

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to share reducer code across state that has similar shape/logic by using generics and the following code compiles fine for both the explicit and inferred `CaseReducer`:

```js
import {
  ActionReducerMapBuilder,
  CaseReducer,
  createAction,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface MyState {
  property: string;
}

const someAction = createAction("some-action");

const one = (builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<MyState>) => {
  builder.addCase(someAction, (state) => ({ ...state })); // ok

  const caseReducer: CaseReducer<
    MyState,{ payload: undefined; type: "some-action" }> = (state: MyState) => ({ ...state });
  builder.addCase(someAction, caseReducer); // ok
};
```

However, when using a type constraint, both explicit and inferred `CaseReducer`s fail:

```js
const two = <T extends MyState>(builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<T>) => {
  builder.addCase(someAction, (state) => ({ ...state })); // type error

  const caseReducer: CaseReducer<
    T,{ payload: undefined; type: "some-action" }> = (state: T) => ({ ...state }); // type error
  builder.addCase(someAction, caseReducer);
};
```

The type error on the explicit `CaseReducer` is as follows:

```
Type '(state: T) => T' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<T, { payload: undefined; type: "some-action"; }>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'Draft<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'Draft<T>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'MyState'.
```

How can I declare `CaseReducer`s with type constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Solved via Type Assertion - by putting `as T` on the return objects.

```js
const two = <T extends MyState>(builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<T>) => {
  builder.addCase(someAction, (state) => ({ ...state } as T)); // ok

  const caseReducer: CaseReducer<
    T,{ payload: undefined; type: "some-action" }> = (state) => ({ ...state } as T); // ok
  builder.addCase(someAction, caseReducer);
};
```